# Look at ebook or website during playing a Vita/PSOne game?

Tags: ps-vita

I just bought *Final Fantasy VII* on the PSN with my Vita and would like to play a 100% Complete game. Therefore I need to look at the FAQ every so often.

Sadly I couldn't find an ebook reader for the Vita yet and also it wants me to quit the game everytime I'm starting the internet browser?

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: unfortunately, there's no way with just the vita :(

Comment: Try this workaround, I don't know if it still works in 1.8, though
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09DdhL3xzd4

Comment: Still works perfectly in 1.8 JohnoBoy. Please post this as an answer!

Comment: I posted as an answer and added some other method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**: As of Vita firmware Ver. 2.00, the browser is now a "tiny app", meaning it can be run alongside game software without quitting (or having to do the Twitter workaround).

Original answer follows:

While the Web Browser isn't directly accessible while running a game (Vita, PSP or PSOne), there is a workaround to surf to websites while using software.

What you need to do is install the LiveTweet app from the PSN store (available for free). This app is accessible while running games. Either enter your twitter credentials and look for a tweet with a link or use the link to authorize the app that's available if no account is entered, clicking the link will open the web browser w/o closing your currently running game and you can browse to whatever guide or eBook you need, please note that minimizing the browser (using the PS button) will require you to enter it again via the Twitter app. Open webpages will need to be reloaded, so make sure you have internet access when you use this method.

Here's a nice video guide on this workaround:

Another semi-awkward method to use guides while playing games is saving the guides as images and loading them to the picture app, this is actually a bit more convenient if you need to move quickly between the game and guide because you can do so without using other software in the middle, but you'll lose the convenience of searching through the text. You can either use the Vita browser and take screenshots (<kbd>PS</kbd>+<kbd>Start</kbd>) or use a Chrome extension like Webpage Screenshot and transfer the files over to your Vita.

Comment: Also, you can use a text-to-speech program to record your text guide and then load it as an MP3 and listen to it while playing, but that's going a bit too far :)

Comment: man, the convolutions you have to go through just to multi task.  I absolutely hate sony software :(

Answer (score 3):

Nope. It's just like the PS3. It won't let you go on the browser / run another application while playing a game. Best bet is to use another device (if possible) to read your FAQ/Guide. Sorry man :(